# Custom Magento admin template blank after 1.4 to 1.6 upgrade

Tags: php, model-view-controller, magento

I have a custom admin module.

site.com/index.php/admin/orderprocess/

After upgrading from 1.4 to 1.6 this module returns a blank page. System.log gives this error:

"2012-01-04T19:47:01+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/orderprocess/item.phtml"

In Magento 1.6, the directory looks like this: app/design/adminhtml/default/cls/template/orderprocess"

Answer (score 1):

You could move your `orderprocess/` directory in `default/cls/template/` to `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/`.  That'll allow Magento to find it.

This method is far easier than changing your Magento adminhtml theme name.

Comment: Is there anyway to add a .xml or something like that will point Magento towards the adminhtml/default/cls folder? There are a couple other things in that folder, and because I'm working on a new and unfamiliar codebase I don't want to make drastic changes.

Moving orderprocess to adminhtml/default/template does fix the problem, but isn't it bad practice to put custom templates in the default folder?

Comment: Actually, it looks like adminhtml/default/default/template is the correct place for this.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the declaration of the adminhtml theme you use in the back office. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448983/magento-override-adminhtml-template-file), you have to declare the theme you want to use for the admin in your module config.xml.

But if you have multiple declaration of this type in several modules, you can have troubles because only the last theme that will be parsed by magento will be used.

In my case, I had two different theme declaration in two modules, that was causing the error 'Not valid template file'.