# Magento - Override adminhtml template file

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have read several posts on stack overflow

- [Overriding a Magento Adminhtml template file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348240/overriding-a-magento-adminhtml-template-file)
- [Magento - overriding Adminhtml block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876897/magento-overriding-adminhtml-block)

and a couple threads on the magento forum

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/21978/

However, None of these posts attempt to do what I am trying to do

I would like to override the

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml
```

file, as this file contains a portion of html that allows anyone to export from the sales->order view.

Note: We have disabled all of the export options for this user role in the permissions->role view

The code that displays the "Export to: " -> "CSV/Excel XML" feature is included in the path I have listed above. I would like to remove that chunk of html and override the file included with Magento.

Comment: I would try to add a local.xml - or better a new layout.xml to your extension and change the template, and remove the export things. Afterwards you need to implement an observer which listens on `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_export_excel` and `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_export_csv` which prevents these actions if the admin_user_group is the wrong

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt Instead of edit core file what is the best alternate like do changes app/design/frontend/default/theme instead of app/design/frontend/default/default

Comment: @zus that what benmarks describes in the accepted solution. Define an admin theme and then use it like a frontend theme - copy file and change what is needed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Adminhtml uses the same theming fallback as the frontend, therefore you need only declare a custom template theme for your installation in module config XML:

```
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <theme>
                <template>custom</template>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Then you can create *app/design/adminhtml/default/custom/template/widget/grid.phtml* with any customizations you like, and this file will be used in preference to the one from the **default/default** adminhtml theme. Your solution then would be to add an ACL check in the logic which renders the export control:

```
<?php if($this->getExportTypes() && {ACL LOGIC}}): ?>
    <td class="export a-right">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/icon_export.gif') ?>" alt="" class="v-middle"/>&nbsp; <?php echo $this->__('Export to:') ?>
        <select name="<?php echo $this->getId() ?>_export" id="<?php echo $this->getId() ?>_export" style="width:8em;">
        <?php foreach ($this->getExportTypes() as $_type): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $_type->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_type->getLabel() ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <?php echo $this->getExportButtonHtml() ?>
    </td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

While this logic might be more appropriately implemented in the block class, the class rewrite system does not accommodate rewriting of parent classes, leaving you to rewrite every subclass. In this instance, obeying DRY outweighs embedding too much logic in templates. Moreover, the change is obvious and easily maintained.

Ideally the core team would have implemented this check in the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` class or at least provided a public setter for the `_exportTypes` property, which would have made this logic a bit cleaner to implement.

Comment: Is it possibile to declare multiple themes as a fallback tree?

Comment: If you move the core adminhtml theme from "default/default" to "base/default" then you can specify three custom themes.

Comment: @benmarks  Instead of edit core file what is the best alternate like do changes app/design/frontend/default/theme instead of app/design/frontend/default/default

Answer (score 5):

It might seem the simplest solution to rewrite the block but that's more of a dirty hack than a clean solution. Class rewrites should be used very carefully and always avoided if possible. Otherwise you will quickly run into conflicts and also updating Magento gets a hell.

Usually you can change templates by a custom layout update (i.e. in your local.xml), but in this case it is a widget, which are not configured via layout XML.

So, enter observers: create a module that contains the following in its `config.xml`

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_block_html_before>
            <observers>
                <yourmodulename_observer>
                    <class>yourmodulename/observer</class>
                    <method>changeWidgetTemplate</method>
                </yourmodulename_observer>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_block_html_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

If you don't understand any of the above, read about Magento Events and Observers.

Now you will need the observer itself to actually change the template, but only for this block type:

```
class Your_Modulename_Observer
{
    public function changeWidgetTemplate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid) {
            // consider getting the template name from configuration
            $template = '...';
            $block->setTemplate($template);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doing this with a local.xml in the admin layout path might be better.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt if you know how to configure **widgets** in local.xml, please let me know. This would indeed be a better solution.

Comment: there is no need of a widget. this might work: <adminhtml_sales_order_index><reference name="sales_order.grid"><action method="setTemplate"><template>newTemplate.phtml</template></...   But I think this won't work, because the block is not created, when the layout is loaded. therefore you are right. The template needs to be changed in an observer.

Answer (score 2):

Magento - Override adminhtml template file
add below code to config.xml file of extension (you created)

```
   <stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <theme>
                <default>default</default>
                <template>rwd</template>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Now create rwd folder under adminhtml/default/rwd package.
and create template and layout file as you want to override.

like we want to override order comment history.phtml file.

```
<root>\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\history.phtml
<root>\app\design\adminhtml\default\rwd\template\sales\order\view\history.phtml
```

Answer (score 1):

Template definition can be found here

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget
```

in

```
public function __construct($attributes=array())
```

So you need to rewrite sales grid block if you want to remove export csv from Sales Order Grid (use this guide if you don't know how http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/174/changing_and_customizing_magento_code) and to change __construct to be like

```
public function __construct($attributes=array())
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->setTemplate('...'); //here is your template
}
```

Comment: This will not work. Block rewriting does not apply to parent classes.

Comment: Yes, the solution suggested by fab is better. But this example will work because you directly rewrite Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid, call its __construct (in which template will be set the first time) and then set your template.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how class rewrites work in Magento. `createBlock('group/name')` uses the config object, but that will autoload only the rewritten class definition, which then specifies the parent class *by name*. The autoloader - which is *solely* responsible when it comes to loading the parent class - does *not in any way* evaluate class rewrites from configuration XML.  Do a simple test with a subclass of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: yes, I know how it works and it was my mistake. sales order grid  needed to be rewriten in this question directly. I changed my answer.

Comment: @freento  Instead of edit core file what is the best alternate like do changes app/design/frontend/default/theme instead of app/design/frontend/default/default