# want to over-ride adminhtml in Magento

Tags: magento, themes, overriding

I have set up a custom theme in Magento admin panel under "Design" tab

I can now put my custom code in

```
 \app\design\frontend\default\MYTHEME\template
```

instead of

```
 \app\design\frontend\base\default\template
```

I would like to do the same for the admin panel code. In other words, I would like to selectively replace vanilla code in this directory

```
  \app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template
```

with custom code, likely in this directory

```
   \app\design\adminhtml\default\MYTHEME\template
```

Magento does not seem to recognize this automatically.

- - - - edit - - -

For the sake of maintainability it would be beneficial to have a global over-ride like we have in 'frontend'.  Over-riding module by module in the module layout may not be obvious to next person that looks at the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448983/magento-override-adminhtml-template-file/14460061#14460061

Comment: I was reading this and other similar questions. Your solution recommends a module by module override.  for the sake of maintainability, is an "all module" solution possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

In /app/code/local/MageIgniter/AdminThemeAndMod/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageIgniter_AdminThemeAndMod>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MageIgniter_AdminThemeAndMod>
    </modules>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <theme>
                    <default>mageigniter</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

In /app/etc/modules/MageIgniter_AdminThemeAndMod.xml

```
<!-- /app/etc/modules/MageIgniter_AdminThemeAndMod.xml -->
 <config>
  <modules>
    <MageIgniter_AdminThemeAndMod>
       <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
     </MageIgniter_AdminThemeAndMod>
    </modules>
 </config>
```

Then add your newly add/update files to

```
/app/design/adminhtml/default/mageigniter/layout/
/app/design/adminhtml/default/mageigniter/template/

/skin/adminhtml/default/mageigniter/
```

Comment: OK. What are we doing here? We create a new module in MageIgniter/AdminThemeAndMod with nothing but a config.xml file. DO all admin files have to go in /mageigniter? - or can it be used for just changes and new phtml and xml?

Comment: Just like the frontend, you only need to add the files you modify

Comment: The settings specified here are redundant; merely specifying `<default>mageigniter` obviates the type-specific declarations.

Answer (score 0):

for "/app/etc/modules/MageIgniter_AdminThemeAndMod.xml", you mean -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- /app/etc/modules/MageIgniter_AdminThemeAndMod.xml -->
 <config>
  <modules>
    <MageIgniter_AdminThemeAndMod>
       <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
     </MageIgniter_AdminThemeAndMod>
    </modules>
 </config>
```